# Does Vuelidate support typescript in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

Does Vuelidate support typescript in VueJs? If yes, how to use?

I am able to use it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the types for this library are shipped separately.

Just install [`@types/vuelidate`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/vuelidate) with npm or yarn

Comment: Also make sure to install it as a dev dependency, as you don't need to build it into your website. You can do so by entering `npm i @types/vuelidate -D`

Comment: I tried installing using types, but no luck. Am I doing something wrong?,

Comment: I had to cast vuelidate to any like below. Then it worked. Vue.use(Vuelidate as any)

Comment: what's the type for the `v` variable (e.g. when passing it components)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Update 2023

Types are included in [@vuelidate/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vuelidate/core)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this github thread.  Specifically [this one](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/175#issuecomment-520963432) works for me.